# For each in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

##I need to iterate over commas to break the characters between comma in xslt. There can be at the max 15 words separated by comma##

```
For example  

`Input  

<root>  
<child>A,B,C,D</child>  
</root>  

Output  
<root>  
<List>A</List>  
<List>B</List>  
<List>C</List>
<List>D</List>  `
```

Comment: please help as im new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **fn:tokenize** to accomplish this. It seperates a string by a delimiter and returns the individual letters without the delimiter.

```
 fn:tokenize("abracadabra", "(ab)|(a)") returns ("", "r", "c", "d", "r", "")
```

For further reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize

Comment: Thanks foe the quick response. However I am using Oracle Jdeveloper Version 11.1.1.5.0. fn:tokenize is not supported by it.

Comment: Please try to be specific as possible about the technologies used in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're using xslt 2.0, because fn:tokenize should work:

(Don't use the 'fn' namespace, this is the default namespace in xpath build in functions)

```xml
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <output>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(child, ',')">
                <child><xsl:value-of select="."/></child>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Example:
http://xsltransform.net/eiQZDbf